# How to log the dbx session in a text file?

Tags: c, debugging, dbx

I generally use dbx for debugging C code.

How do we log the complete session of the dbx from the point I started to the point I fired the quit command in dbx?

Answer (score 1):

If there isn't a specific way in dbx, you can use script.

Before starting dbx, run script.  This starts a new shell where you can run any command (such as dbx).  After you have quit from dbx, quit the sub-shell started by script and you'll find your full dbx session in the file 'typescript'.